# Copy a table into another without duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a bash script to copy one table into another and then it will delete all the records from the original table, but I have a problem.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE AS SELECT DISTINCT * INTO $TABLE FROM T1 WHERE DTA_RIF < TRUNC (SYSDATE -30);
DELETE FROM T1 WHERE DTA_RIF < TRUNC (SYSDATE -30);
```

With this query I have duplicates and I don't want to insert same records. I don't have a PK, so I can't do a join.
I thought with `DISTINCT` I'd solve my problem, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: This is not Oracle, I'd say. Which database do you really use?

Comment: @Littlefoot  I'm using Oracle. I did something wrong?

Comment: This looks suspicious to me: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`; there's no "if not exists" clause in any Oracle version I know (which is 12.2; can't tell for higher versions).

Comment: Looks like mysql

Comment: @Marietto: what does `select version 
from product_component_version
where product like 'Oracle%';` give you?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Version 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: The that statement won't execute at all, because it is invalid for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

you may be getting duplicate records because the records do not match other records exactly in all columns, you might be able to solve this by using one column as reference for the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM T1 WHERE DTA_RIF < TRUNC (SYSDATE -30);

with this query you can get the distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

OK then, Oracle it is. As clause you used doesn't work there, you'll have to drop it first, then create it. Depending on whether you want to just *ignore* existence of the table, you could choose one of the following options; examples are based on Scott's sample schema as I don't have your tables.

### Drop + Create

```
SQL> DROP TABLE dist_emp;
DROP TABLE dist_emp
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> CREATE TABLE dist_emp
  2  AS
  3     SELECT DISTINCT *
  4       FROM emp
  5      WHERE hiredate < TRUNC (SYSDATE - 30);

Table created.

SQL>
```

### Use PL/SQL to drop it if it exists + Create

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_table_name  VARCHAR2 (30);
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT table_name
  5       INTO l_table_name
  6       FROM user_tables
  7      WHERE table_name = 'DIST_EMP';
  8
  9     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table dist_emp';
 10  EXCEPTION
 11     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 12     THEN
 13        NULL;
 14  END;
 15  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> CREATE TABLE dist_emp
  2  AS
  3     SELECT DISTINCT *
  4       FROM emp
  5      WHERE hiredate < TRUNC (SYSDATE - 30);

Table created.

SQL>
```

### Create once + Truncate + Insert

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE dist_emp
  2  AS
  3     SELECT *
  4       FROM emp
  5      WHERE 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE dist_emp;

Table truncated.

SQL> INSERT INTO dist_emp
  2     SELECT DISTINCT *
  3       FROM emp
  4      WHERE hiredate < TRUNC (SYSDATE - 30);

14 rows created.

SQL> -- Next time: don't drop it, just truncate its contents
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE dist_emp;

Table truncated.

SQL> INSERT INTO dist_emp
  2     SELECT DISTINCT *
  3       FROM emp
  4      WHERE hiredate < TRUNC (SYSDATE - 30);

14 rows created.

SQL>
```

---

Additionally:

- I'd suggest you to always specify all columns involved into that operation. Don't use `*`. It is convenient for testing & demonstration purposes, but for production - name all of them, e.g.

  ```
  insert into dist_emp (deptno, empno, ename, job, sal)
  select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal
  from emp
  where hiredate < trunc(sysdate - 30);
  ```
- subtracting 30 from sysdate looks like a *previous month*. If that's so, well, it won't work for about 50% of all cases (because months tend to have 28/29, 30 or 31 days). A safer option might be `ADD_MONTHS` function, e.g.

  ```
  where hiredate < trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1))
  ```